# How to use on() after removing the click event off()?

Tags: jquery

off() is removing the click event handle.

on() was supposed to rebind the effect, but is not working

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').on('click', function(){
        $(this).css('color', 'blue');
    });
    $('#btn_off').click(function(){
        $('p').off('click');
    });
    $('#btn_on').click(function(){
        $('p').on('click');
    });
});
</script>

<span>Click the paragraph:</span>
<p>Prg #1</p>
<p>Prg #2</p>
<p>Prg #3</p>
<p>Prg #4</p>
<button id="btn_off">bind off prg.</button>
<button id="btn_on">bind on prg.</button>
```

See my question in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing the click handler while bind event.

*Use*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Declare click handler
    var pClickHandler = function(){
        $(this).css('color', 'blue');
    }

    //Bind click handler on document ready
    $('p').on('click', pClickHandler);


    $('#btn_on').click(function(){
         //Bind click handler on on click
        $('p').on('click', pClickHandler);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you all, I'll accept @Satpal for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/bijina/2/edit?html,js,output)

```
$(function() { // DOM Ready shorthand

  function changeColor() {
       $(this).css('color', 'blue');
  }

  $('#btn_off').click(function() {
     $('p').off('click', changeColor);  // Turn OFF
  });
  $('#btn_on').click(function() {
     $('p').on('click', changeColor);   // Turn ON
  }).trigger("click");                  // Activate. Same as doing: 
                                        // $('p').on('click', changeColor);

});
```